# Alfresco custom login page, No 'login' page type configured - but page auth required it

Tags: customization, alfresco

I'm trying to create a custom login page following this documentaiuon http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/dev-extensions-share-tutorials-override-login-page.html
 and this http://blog.arvixe.com/customize-alfresco-share-login-page/
But I couldn't get it works and the log show this exceptio,:

```
org.springframework.extensions.surf.exception.PlatformRuntimeException: 03110000 No 'login' page type configured - but page auth required it.
```

And the page web shows this massages:
 server error has occurred.

There are a number of reasons why this could have happened:

> ```
> You have attempted to access a page that does not exist - check the URL in the address bar.
> You have attempted to access a page that is not accessible to you, such as a private Site dashboard.
> A valid page has been requested but the server was unable to render it due to an internal error - contact your administrator.<br/>
> ```

Here all my config:
share-config-custom.xml

```
   <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="WebFramework">
      <web-framework>
         <defaults>
            <page-type>
               <id>login</id>
               <page-instance-id>mhg-login</page-instance-id>
            </page-type>
         </defaults>
      </web-framework>
   </config>
```

template/instances/mhg-login.xml

```
<template-instance>
   <template-type>mhg/mhg-login</template-type>
</template-instance>
```

pages/mhg-login.xml :

```
<page>
   <template-instance>mhg-login</template-instance>
   <authentication>none</authentication>
</page>
```

Comment: What version of alfresco are you on ? and can you attach your customizations ?

Comment: I'm not sure what was the problem, but it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you've got the wrong path for your template:
If you copy it from here:

https://github.com/teqnology/alfresco-login-reset-share

you'll see that your template/instances/mhg-login.xml is wrongly configured:

the correct template path is `/src/main/amp/config/alfresco/web-extension/site-data/template-instances` and the content should be the path to your file which in your case should have a `mhg` folder (`mhg/mhg-login`) which I don't see in your details.
Make sure you create the correct path, and you point it to the correct file.
Cheers

Comment: I'm not using a module, I put extention on tomcat/share/classes/alfresco

Comment: in the official doc it say template-instances but the other blog put template/instances

Comment: it doesn't matter if you're using a module or not, the path remains the same, stripped down of `/src/main/amp/config`. Refer to the github project and copy the paths from there, and you should be fine